# imagettftext, font doesn't have & sign, how to use different font for it or how to show it?

Tags: php, fonts, imagettftext

First of all is it possible to do that? If font doesn't have & sign and I need to show it, is it possible like in css to use extra font for those characters? Because of & sign it is showing empty space. I tried to use `&#38;` and `&amp;` instead & sign(I have used and only & sign), but still nothing helped. Maybe you have any idea, how to do that with imagettftext ? Thanks in advance

Comment: This URL can help you for CSS.. please go through it.. http://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/